# Passing store to switchMap function in observable epic

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I need to pass store value to switchMap function on epic but seems like only action is passed and store is 0.

```
export const addVideoEpic = (action$, store) =>
      action$.ofType(videoTypes.ADD_VIDEO_REQUEST)
             .filter(() => of(store.getState()))
             .switchMap((action, store) => {
               const data = {
                url: store.url
               };
               console.log(store) // 0
               return from(addVideo(data))
             });
```

How to pass store value down to switchMap

Comment: I don't know anything about redux-observable, but your third line seems wrong. Filter is used to filter out values from an rx stream. I think what you want to do instead is replace the filter line with  ```.withLatestFrom(store.getState())``` or something similar instead. If you use withLatestFrom then you might have to change your switchMap statement to ```.switchMap(([action, store]) => {```.

Comment: My comment above had the assumption that store.getState() returns an Observable of the state. If that is not the case and store.getState() directly returns the state you should be able to remove the filter line and remove the store parameter from the arrow function in the switchMap. The store is already passed in by the outer arrow function and should be also available inside of switchmap.

Answer (score 1):

In order to pass a store into the epic, your epic must be aware of the existence of a store. In your store creation class, please make sure that you have something like:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer as Reducer)

export const store = createStore(
 persistedReducer,
 applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware)
);

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
```

And assuming that your version of `redux-observable` is `^1.0.0` or newer and `rxjs` is `^6.0.0` or newer, you can access the store and whatever state it stores as such:

```
export function fetchRandomStuffEpic(
  action$: ActionsObservable<RandomAction>,
  store$: StateObservable<RootState>
) {
     return action$.pipe(
     ofType(RANDOM),
     switchMap(action => {

      // store.getState() no longer works in the newer versions
      // and has to accessed as a value property with store$
      const { authToken } = store$.value.userData;

     // whatever code that follows
    })
 );
}
```